# Ansible No such file or directory error message for any executable in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2, linux

I'm trying to run this command in a Amazon Linux AMI instance

```
  - name: Run docker
    shell: systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
```

And receiving this error message

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh: systemctl: No such file or directory"
```

I already tried with `command`, ansible systemd module and `/usr/bin/systemctl`.

Comment: Try `command: which systemctl` and `command: hostname`

Comment: Same error `{"changed": false, "cmd": "wich systemctl", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for a time I solved the problem by changing the image in the ci from Ubuntu to ansible-runner.